# Reverse engineering: Extract images/sprite sheet from apk

Tags: android, apk, sprite, reverse-engineering, sprite-sheet

I'm learning about game development and I'm trying to extract some resources from some games that I love to play, I'm doing this just to learn more about sprites and resource organization.
The problem is every game I extract the images come with some kind of problem, sometimes just doesn't open and other times I can open the image but I see just some pixels.

Is there any resource protection used in the apk market? Is there any way to extract and see these sprite sheet?

Just remember I'm doing this just for the PURPOSE OF LEARNING and I will not use it in any of my games or projects!

Thanks for any help and have a nice day guys :).

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try ApkTool (http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) to decode the APK:

```
apktool d myapp.apk
```

This will decode the resources properly.

Comment: It didn't worked to me :(. After I used the apktool I tried to open the imagens but i received this message from windows: "windows photo viewer can't open this picture because the file appears to be damaged corrupted". 
I tried to decode the apk "Castle Defense" from google play.
Can you give me any tip?